# Vectorization of a nested for-loop

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, vectorization

I have a function, `roughness` that is called quite often in a larger piece of code. I need some help with replacing this double for-loop with a simpler vectorized version. Here is the code below:

```
def roughness(c,d,e,f,z,ndim,half_tile,dx):
    imin=0-half_tile
    imax=half_tile
    z_calc = np.zeros((ndim,ndim), dtype=float)
    for j in range(ndim):
        y=(j-half_tile)*dx
        for i in range(ndim):
            x=(i-half_tile)*dx
            z_calc[i,j] = c*x*y + d*x + e*y + f - z[i,j]

    z_min=z_calc[z_calc!=0].min()
    z_max=z_calc[z_calc!=0].max()

    # Calculate some statistics for the difference tile

    difference = np.reshape(z_calc,ndim*ndim)

    mean = np.mean(difference)
    var = stats.tvar(difference,limits=None)
    skew = stats.skew(difference,axis=None)
    kurt = stats.kurtosis(difference, axis=None)

    return(z_min,z_max,mean,var,skew,kurt)
```

After the main calculations, the various stats are calculated on them. The values, of `c,d,e,f, ndim,half_tile` are all single integer values, and the variable `z` is an array with size `ndim x ndim` I have tried to vectorize this before, but the values do not come out correctly, although the code does run.

Here is my attempt:

```
def roughness(c,d,e,f,z,ndim,half_tile,dx):

    z_calc = np.zeros((ndim,ndim), dtype=float)
    x = np.zeros((ndim,ndim), dtype=float)
    y = np.zeros((ndim,ndim), dtype=float)

    x,y = np.mgrid[1:ndim+1,1:ndim+1]
    x = (x-half_tile)*dx
    y = (y-half_tile)*dx

    z_calc = c*x*y + d*x + e*y + f - z

    z_min=z_calc[z_calc!=0].min()
    z_max=z_calc[z_calc!=0].max()

    # Calculate some statistics for the difference tile

    difference = np.reshape(z_calc,ndim*ndim)

    mean = np.mean(difference)
    var = stats.tvar(difference,limits=None)
    skew = stats.skew(difference,axis=None)
    kurt = stats.kurtosis(difference, axis=None)

    return(z_min,z_max,mean,var,skew,kurt)
```

Aside from getting the correct values, I would really like to know if I did the vectorization of the nested for loop correctly, which i'm assuming I didn't.

Comment: `for j in range(ndim)` is not equivalent to `x,y =np.mgrid[1:ndim+1,1:ndim+1]` . why the shift ? ( np.mgrid[:ndim,:ndim] seems the equivalent here)

Comment: I'm not sure why, but if I define `x,y =np.mgrid[1:ndim,1:ndim]`, I get an error saying the array is one less than the previously defined `z_calc`  variable. for example if `z_calc` is a `13 x 13` array, if I define x,y using ndim instead of ndim +1, then it will say: "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,12) (13,13)"

Comment: Try `x,y =np.mgrid[0:ndim,0:ndim]`, and I think it will work.